# Distribution of molecular speeds (kinetic theory of gases)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

What is the physical significance of the $N(v)$? I know that the product $N(v)\ dv$ gives the number of molecules in a given speed range of $v$ to $v+dv$ but is there any meaning of $N(v)$ itself? Here, by $N(v)$ I mean to say the Maxwell Speed distribution.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: It seems like you have answered your own question.

Comment: @kaylimekay Sorry, but I didn't get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key concept you may be missing is that of a probability density. There are - roughly speaking - two types of ways probability occurs in physics. They depend on the number of possible outcomes of a probability experiment. That would in your case mean randomly choosing a particle and measuring its velocity, where the measured value $v$ is the outcome of the experiment.

1. Discrete outcomes: Only a countable number of outcomes is possible. The standard example is rolling dice, where outcomes can range from 1 to 6. The number of outcomes may be finite or infinte, we don't need to get into technicalities, though.
2. Continuous outcomes: An uncountable range, say an interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, of outcomes is possible. You can imagine making a random tick on a ruler and measuring where the tick lands.

The problem you are describing is of the second class, since any non-negative real number is a possible value of the modulus of the velocity. However, if one has uncountably many outcomes, there is a problem. Say you want to determine the probability of finding the velocity $400$ m$/$s. You keep measuring particle velocities, and with time you will find velocities that are closer and closer to $400$ m$/$s. But you will never measure exactly $400$ m$/$s, because the set of possible outcomes is continuous.

In a very real way, one must concede that the probability of finding a particle of the exact velocity $400$ m$/$s is 0. There is of course a workaround: We introduce a probability density $N(v)$ and make the statement that for a small enough volume $dv$ around $v$, the actual probability is given by the density times the volume, that is $N(v)dv$.

So, $N(v)$ is a density, which is not quite a probability without providing some volume. The good thing is: our measurements are not perfectly precise. So, when measuring a particle velocity, you will get a value $\tilde v$ which is somewhere in $v \pm \Delta v$, where $\Delta v$ is the measurement error and $v$ is the velocity of the particle.

Answer (score 1):

> Basics

*Probability density function* :

[The probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is a function whose value at any given sample (or point) in the sample space (the set of possible values taken by the random variable) can be interpreted as providing a relative likelihood that the value of the random variable would equal that sample.

In other words, while the absolute likelihood for a continuous random variable to take on any particular value is $0$ (since there are an infinite set of possible values to begin with), the value of the PDF at two different samples can be used to infer, in any particular draw of the random variable, how much more likely it is that the random variable would equal one sample compared to the other sample.

For Example : Suppose bacteria of a certain species typically live $4$ to $6$ hours. The probability that a bacterium lives exactly $5$ hours is equal to zero. A lot of bacteria live for approximately $5$ hours, but there is no chance that any given bacterium dies at exactly $5.0000000000...$ hours. However, the probability that the bacterium dies between $5$ hours and $5.01$ hours is quantifiable.

> On Question

[Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) is a particular probability distribution (named after James Clerk Maxwell and Ludwig Boltzmann).

A rest of the answer follows from the above definition of density function i.e. What $f(v)$ is?

A system's distribution function is a function of seven variables, $f(x,y,z,v_x,v_y,v_z,t)$ which gives the number of particles per unit volume in single-particle phase space. It is the number of particles per unit volume having approximately the velocity $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ near the position $(x,y,z)$ and time $t$.